# How do I get debug_backtrace() to fire on the endpoint site of a Deployment process?

Tags: debugging, deployment

I'm trying to work through this [UUID features bug](http://drupal.org/node/1390708) with the deploy module. On the receiving site, I see errors in that log like

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'fc661e5c-62de-fa34-2557-0f6f5a2acbfe' for column 'fid'
```

I've followed the example laid out [here](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/quick-and-dirty-debugging) to have a backtrace show for any error on both the sending and receiving installations. However I can' seem to find a way to get the backtrace to show for the error on the receiving site after the deploy process completes. I can see the service error in /admin/reports/dblog but that's it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-adbo

Answer (score 2):

note the following: **fc661e5c-62de-fa34-2557-0f6f5a2acbfe**
and then... **General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:**

the number or UUID is not an integer.

therefore you'll get that sort of error message. I'm assuming deploy has either a bug in it or you've forgotten to run **update.php** on your DB the FID field is marked in the DB as an integer when it should be a varchar / string field.

Take a look at the schema and see what needs to change. that should at least give you an indication of where things have gone wrong.